# Which linux based distribution is best in terms of performance?

Tags: lubuntu, debian

Solely if I just consider performance of machine which distribution I should install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ubuntu leads in linux distributions.**

Check these links for more information.

[Ubuntu Vs Fedora Vs OpenSuSE](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=opensuse-intel-broadwell&num=1)

Comment: I would disagree with you. When considering performance, the distros that first come to my mind are lightweight ones, and Ubuntu does not stand any where top on that list. I would rather go with, say Arch linux, Bodhi or something alike. The benchmark you provide in link compares only those 3 distros, not all the 280+ distros mentioned on distrowatch.com.


 This to say apart from the fact that this question is off topic here.